# "Creating publish preview" Suddenly very slow to LocalDB

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, localdb

I'm using LocalDB to mock up a SQLServer DB in Visual Studio 2013. It's been working well but suddenly when I publish my changes to the DB, the "creating publish preview" step is taking several minutes whereas it used to take only a few seconds. The Database has not suddenly become very large (about 6 stored procedures and 6 tables) or changes to any great extent.

Can anyone suggest why this might be and what I can do to resolve it? It's pretty much unworkable having to wait several minutes every time I change anything and want to test it.

Comment: I don't know if it helps, but because I have to deal with this all the time with large database projects, I've been doing my development directly in SSMS, editing the VS files from there (make sure to check out first if using source control). For many changes (e.g. stored procedures) you just have to change ALTER to CREATE when you're satisfied.
I make it a point to postpone publishes as far into development as possible because it takes soooo long, and I *really* try to head off code errors that would fail the publish when I finally try it.

Comment: I won't post this as an answer, as I've not investigated it enough, but for me re-recreating the connection in my publishing profile helped it.